# how to copy data from on cell to diferrent cell using command button

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

for example the first thing i put in cell b1 has "='Ex-post'!C172"which has value "1"  and c1 has "=OFFSET('Ex-post'!$B$4,MATCH($H$1,'Ex-post'!$B$5:$B$542, 0),4)" in which the value is 2300 and i want to copy only the value c1 to cell h1, then value in cell b1 and c1 will be change in to like b1 "2" and c1 "2800" then value from c1 must copy to cell h2. how can i create 1 command button that i just click every time cell b1 and c1 value change, c1 value would be paste on different location based on the value on cell b1.

i hope somebody can help me... thanks

Comment: You would need a macro that reacts to worksheet changes. What have you tried already and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

After placing your button on the worksheet, assign this macro to it:

```
Sub CopyStuff()
    Range("C1").Copy Range("H" & Range("B1").Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but how about "c1 and B1" is from SHeet1 while "h1" is from sheet2. what do i need to add? my command button is placed on sheet1.